# Using wifi and ethernet at the same time

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, network-adapter

I want to use my ethernet unlimited internet for downloading and normal browsing (so I want chrome and the download manager to use it)

At the same time I want to use a wifi metered internet for a game or a program that needs a good ping.

Is it possible to use 2 internet connections and have 2 IPs at the same time ? each network card should work with a separate program or set of programs.

Thank you for any help, I found nothing on this (not even attempts or explanations)

Comment: the NIC used by a connection is established by the destination IP, so (with the exception of server application's LISTENING ports), an application cannot choose which interface its traffic will exit over. If your particular game uses IP addresses you can identify, you can create IP routes that send traffic to those specific IPs out a given interface, but it will only work for those destinations, and they need to be quite specific so that they override the existing routes out the ethernet nic.

Comment: The solution would be platform specific due to different network stack implementations. Please update your question and specify which OS you are working on.